# A doubt regarding the calculation of inverse matrices

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse

I am attaching the solution of a school question asking to calculate the inverse of a matrix. However, the solution proposed does not fit in anything I ever seen about calculating inverse matrices. I did not found any property that fits the final part of the solution (the one I highlighted in the image below) although the solution is correct, I would like to know which property or reasoning supports the final solution of such a problem. Thanks. [image]

Comment: The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) is $$\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(\mathbf{A})} \operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A})$$